# mysterious white antialiasing behind UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm using a PageViewController to swipe through a series of daily ViewControllers for a week.

The UIViewController that contains the pageViewController contains a few navigation items that do not scroll with the pageViewController.  These stay stationary as you swipe.  One of these items is a UIImageView, more specifically a UIButton with an UIImageView image representation.

The trouble I'm having is that this stationary UIImageView has a thin white border to it when it should not.  I'm giving it a rounded appearance by using rounded corners that are the size of the image.  It is easiest seen in this photo.  Note, the white "halo" is not part of the image, it appears for any image. The borderColor, imageBackground, view background, and parent view backgrounds are all clearColor.  The red background below is part of the swipeable viewController.  Interestingly, the white border only appears when it is stationary.  If the image/button is placed in the swipeable View it looks great.

Any thoughts how I can get rid of this white antialiasing?

[image]

Comment: This type of problem is often due to having non-integral frames - the size or origin. Just double check.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the button's image from using the backgroundImage to just the image property and the white went away entirely.  Glad for an easy fix, hope this helps someone else.